# Trying to load remote image to ImageView, but nothing happens

Tags: android, image, imageview

I'm using the following function to load a remote image to an ImageView. The image definitely exists at the URL I'm trying to load it from but when I call to the function and try to display the image the ImageView remains blank.

```
public static void setImage(ImageView view, String url) throws IOException {
    final URLConnection conn = new URL(url).openConnection();
    conn.connect();
    final InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();

    final BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is, 100000);

    final Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bis);
    bis.close();
    is.close();

    view.setImageBitmap(bm);
}
```

Comment: I corrected a small thing in my code in the case you have copied it already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this worked for me:

```
    Bitmap bitmap = null;

    HttpGet httpRequest = null;


    try {
            URL url = new URL(your_url);
            httpRequest = new HttpGet(url.toURI());

            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpResponse response = (HttpResponse) httpclient.execute(httpRequest);

            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            BufferedHttpEntity bufHttpEntity = new BufferedHttpEntity(entity); 
            InputStream instream = bufHttpEntity.getContent();
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(instream);
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
```

Comment: This gives me a Runtime Exception.

Comment: You probably missing the photo_not_found in /drawable/, just remove those 3 lines. And check that you have the necessary permissions!

Comment: I already did that, still throwing Runtime exception. What do you mean necessary permissions? How can I check that?

Comment: In your AndroidManifest.xml you should have the line <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>

Comment: It's working - I had to do it in the background, it was throwing the network activity on main thread exception. Thanks a lot man.

Comment: Always good to help :) I still recomend looking at the ignition-libary. I tend to use this more because it's just simpler and already has a progress-wheel built in...

Comment: I would - but I'm such a newbie when it comes to Eclipse and Android that it was too much trouble for me to figure out how to import and use the external library not to mention use that custom class in my main.xml file LOL.

Answer (score 0):

It might be an option to use https://github.com/kaeppler/ignition, try the RemoteImageView, it's pretty easy to use.

Comment: Man, if I had any idea how to import an external library and use it in my project I would. All I get are "can't be resolved" errors on the import github...*; statements.

Comment: Just import the ignition-core project into eclipse. Then go to your project settings (Rightclick -> Properties) and choose "Android". At the bottom click on "add" and add the ignition-core project. Hope it works :)

Comment: When I click "Add", the pop-up is empty. No choices.

Comment: make sure that the ignition-core porject is an android-project and in it's setttings under android the tick "Is libary" is ticked. Then it should work.

Comment: anybody knows what happened with this link? seems they moved out of github

Comment: I found his email address here: http://repos.io/project/github/kaeppler/ignition/readme/ Maybe if you contact him he can tell you what's up...

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
private void setImage(String urlStr, ImageView iv) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet(urlStr);
    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
    InputStream is = response.getEntity().getContent();
    TypedValue typedValue = new TypedValue();
    typedValue.density = TypedValue.DENSITY_NONE;
    Drawable drawable = Drawable.createFromResourceStream(null, typedValue, is, "src");
    iv.setImageDrawable(drawable);
}
```

Note: It loads synchronously. If it works your next step should be load in a thread, to not block the main thread.

Comment: I'm getting FlushedInputStream can not be resolved although I have java.io.*; imported...

Comment: I wrote you a comment to please update the code, I copied it from some code I have and you don't need that class. Changed it, you can try again.

Comment: That gives me this error: The constructor FilterInputStream(InputStream) is not visible.

Comment: Igh, sorry, you don't need a FilterInputStream there, just pass the InputStream is (corrected the code again...)

Comment: Glad to help. Just to inform, in the case you don't know yet, you should also mark an answer as accepted, when it solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I use [Prime](https://github.com/DHuckaby/Prime) for all of my image loading. It can handle this easily.